# Grails and Spring Security: Salt Value Must Be Null When Use with Crypto Module PasswordEncoder

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've almost completed my upgrade of a Grails 2.2.1 to 2.3.4 and Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3 to 2.0 RC2. I have the application running, but when I try to login I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Salt value must be null when used with crypto module PasswordEncoder
```

I haven't been able to figure this out and I haven't found any useful tips for this error related to grails or spring security plugin...

I have the salts setup with a custom UserDetailsService as laid out in this blog posting:
  http://grailsplayground.blogspot.com/2011/10/setting-up-grails-web-application-using.html

I don't know if I need to be doing the salts differently (if the new plugin has a better way to do it) or if I just needed to change something small (like I had to do through the upgrade process of changing grails.plugins.springsecurity to grails.plugin.springsecurity)

log4j output (trying to authenticate):

```
    web.FilterChainProxy  - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
    rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
    rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Cancelling cookie
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default algorithm in 2.0 is bcrypt which doesn't support a supplied salt because it uses its own internally. So unconfigure any salt-related settings (e.g. the `dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty` property or a custom `saltSource` bean) and use the default, or override the default with the `password.algorithm` property (e.g. with SHA-256) and configure salt settings.

Comment: Ok, I elected to use SH-256 with my existing customized UserDetails (at least for now). I added the password.algorithm to my config.groovy to use SHA-256. I don't get an error message anymore, BUT none of the users are being authenticated...

Comment: I enabled log4j debug logging, If I try to authenticate a user with a password hash (SHA-256 and a salt) the output reads that it fails after filter 3 (I updated question with output).  If I try to authenticate with a user that has null in the salt column, I get the same logging output

Comment: If the passwords were hashed with 1.2.x you probably need to add `grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations=1` to Config.groovy since the new default is 10000.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much Burt