# Password hashing with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, salt, bcrypt

Is it possible to add additional salt to password using Spring Security BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Comment: Might be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080777/grails-and-spring-security-salt-value-must-be-null-when-use-with-crypto-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Bcrypt algorithm with a custom salt since in `bcrypt algorithm it always chooses a random salt to encode the password and and then finally it attaches the salt to the encoded password.` This how it works, that is the reason that you cannot have your own custom salt in this algorithm.

Even the error message that you are getting shows the same thing. You should instead use SHA-256 or MD5 algorithms if you want to use custom salt source for encryption.