# Different hashes given by Spring Security 4 in Grails 4.0.0 using sha256

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, sha256

I'm trying to use password hashes generated with sha256  from a legacy project in  grails 2.3.8 I was trying to prepend {sha256} to the hashes in the data base in order avoid 'There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"' Exception but I've noticed every time the encoder generate a hash is a different hash, so when I type the password never matches with the original hash.

I think is because salt but I didn't set a salt source

This is my configuration in application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'sha256'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1
```

This are some hashes generated with the same password: 'support' and this is the username='zzzz'

```
{sha256}36a0d0f4ce590497957078784dddbefe675c2ea06f4ed7c1b1ad57f2442b4c27f3b611def0ad5141

{sha256}5b4c2a5616cfe3a2b1f82e58890c5c8ff7cf8dba81d8ec692c493143719b3c6bca54ca1b48dba218
```

Comment: Did you try to set a salt source?

Comment: I've tried with this property grails.plugin.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty = 'username' but didn't work as I expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080777/grails-and-spring-security-salt-value-must-be-null-when-use-with-crypto-module this that `hash.iterations = 1` relates to version 1.2 -- worth a read https://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2017